# How do I edit a Unity InputField by clicking on Android UI Button?

Tags: unity, c#, android

I have been stuck on this problem for a long time and not sure what I need to do. Would appreciate any help.

I am building an Android app using `Unity`. In my app I have an `InputField`, a `TMP_InputField` to be precise, in my Unity scene as a `Prefab`. I want to edit this input field by clicking on a button in my Android UI *(not part of Unity scene)*. I don't want the input field to be editable by clicking on the input field itself.

In order to achieve this, I enabled the Hide Soft keyboard option in the editor so that user can't edit the field by clicking on the field. But I am not able to figure out how to edit the input field.

First problem is how to pop up the keyboard when I click on the Android button. I tried this.

```
TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("");
```

This pops up the keyboard but the input field doesn't show the caret and doesn't accept input.

I also tried,

```
EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(inputField.gameObject, null);
inputField.OnPointerClick(null);
```

and

```
inputField.Select();
inputField.ActivateInputField();
```

But no success. I tried to play with the `focused`, `interactable`, `activated` properties but nothing works.

This should be easy but I am unable to get it to work. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks!